# HTTP Get Request returning error of HTTPS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

I was implementing a Get Request with axios and useEffect from React, and I was trying to access the weatherstack, however, there was an error, and I checked to see that the console logged back

```
Object { code: 105, type: "https_access_restricted", info: "Access Restricted - Your current Subscription Plan does not support HTTPS Encryption." }
```

I have the code below, and I have checked that it is http, so I'm unsure why this occurs. I also happened to see that refreshing it multiple times, like 5% of the times, it was able to go through, so is this an error of my code or something else? I'm not sure what is indicating that this is https, since I have used http in the url.

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios
    .get("http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=API_KEY&query=Bern")
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data)
    })
}, [])
```

Comment: what happens if you open the URL in the browser directly

Answer (score 0):

If your React app is running on a page that is served over HTTPS, the browser will automatically upgrade requests from HTTP to HTTPS if an HTTPS version is available. Google's [Fixing mixed content](https://web.dev/fixing-mixed-content/) article describes this in detail.

As far as I'm aware, you can only avoid this if you serve your own page over HTTP as well. Because even if you were to somehow disable the automatic HTTP-to-HTTPS, you would probably still get a mixed content warning because you're requesting insecure content from a secure page.